# Using org-ref in beamer mode

Tags: beamer, org-ref

I am trying to export an org-beamer file to pdf. I have references that I inserted them by using org-ref. I can see some of my references in the last page but not all them because they do not fit into a single page (or frame).

How can I show all my references ?

B.R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to allow frame breaking by adding the corresponding Beamer option as an Org property to the slide heading:

```
 * References
 :PROPERTIES:
 :BEAMER_opt: allowframebreaks,label=
 :END:
 bibliographystyle:unsrt
 bibliography:/path/to/my.bib
```

Comment: Can you post a complete org-mode example file? Does `bibliography:/path/to/my.bib` even work? Shouldn't directives start with `#+`?

Comment: I think it works with org-ref what the question was about. It is org-cite which uses a directive for specifying the bibliography.